# How to check if the user purchased an item?

Tags: android

I have a functional code of IAP and everything is working fine and I have a shared preference that stores if the item is purchased or not and the app acts upon the value but the problem is when the user uninstalls the app the sharedpreferences is deleted so when he re-installs the app the item will be available for purchase plus if he tried to buy it again he won't be able to since he already owns this item. so I wanted to know how to check if the item is purchased or not, Thanks.

Comment: Then I think you need to store the items purchased on server database and retrieve the values from there through network call with API